# How to delete NULL elements from nested table in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I have used `nested_table_type_variable.extend()` to extend my nested table and after that i am assigning values to the extend spaces. However at the end of my processing i see many empty spaces are added to my table and i wanted them to be removed. Can you please help in knowing how exactly i can remove `empty space` rows from my nested table in `oracle plsql`?

Comment: Please post your code, or a simplified version of it which demonstrates the problem you're experiencing. At the moment all we can do is provide guesses, and that's just a waste of everybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

Note: `NULL` values in a list are not empty spaces. You get empty spaces when you use `DELETE` to remove indexes from the collection.

> How exactly can I remove empty space rows from my nested table?

If you want to remove deleted elements and `NULL` elements then you can write a procedure to compact the list:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE compact_list(
  list IN OUT INT_LIST
)
IS
  i   PLS_INTEGER;
  idx PLS_INTEGER;
  cnt PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  idx := list.FIRST;
  cnt := list.COUNT;
  i   := 1;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN i > cnt;
    
    IF list(idx) IS NULL THEN
      cnt := cnt - 1;
    ELSE
      list(i) := list(idx);
      i := i + 1;
    END IF;
    
    idx := list.NEXT(idx);
  END LOOP;

  IF list.COUNT > cnt THEN
    list.TRIM(list.COUNT - cnt);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample list:

```sql
DECLARE
  list INT_LIST := INT_LIST(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NULL,9);
BEGIN
  list.DELETE(3);
  list.DELETE(5);
  list.DELETE(6);

  compact_list(list);
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. list.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i || ': ' || list(i));
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Compacts the list removing the deleted values and outputs:

> ```
> 1: 1
> 2: 2
> 3: 4
> 4: 7
> 5: 9
> ```

---

If you want a function, rather than a procedure, then:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION compact_list_fn(
  i_list IN INT_LIST
) RETURN INT_LIST DETERMINISTIC
IS
  o_list INT_LIST := INT_LIST();
  i      PLS_INTEGER;
  idx    PLS_INTEGER;
  cnt    PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  idx := i_list.FIRST;
  cnt := i_list.COUNT;
  i   := 1;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN i > cnt;
    
    IF i_list(idx) IS NULL THEN
      cnt := cnt - 1;
    ELSE
      o_list.EXTEND();
      o_list(i):= i_list(idx);
      i := i + 1;
    END IF;
    
    idx := i_list.NEXT(idx);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN o_list;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc18aca9f4e9f9291d21aa959a094ac9)*